# "Writing" inside a HTML page using JS and JS scope

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm developing a program which basically just receives input from the user twice (risk carrier and sum, but that's just a placeholder to make my program less abstract), groups those two values together and then repeats the contents in a loop. See the code below.

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fillArray(){
    document.getElementById("danke").innerHTML = "Thanks for specifying the amount of entries.";
    var numberOfEntries = parseInt(document.getElementById('input0').value);
    var i = 0;
    var myArrA = [];
    var myArrB = [];
    var x = " ";
    while(i<numberOfEntries){
       var neuRT = prompt("Enter a risk carrier");
       myArrA.push(neuRT);
       var neuRH = prompt("Enter a risk sum");
       myArrB.push(neuRH);
       i++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i<anzahlEintraege; i++){
        x = myArrA[i] + " carries a risk of " + myArrB[i];
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
    }

}


</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>risk assessment</h1>

<input type="text" id="input0" />
<button type="button" onclick="fillArray()">Number of entries</button> <p id="danke"></p>

<button type="button" onclick="untilNow()">Show all entries so far</button>
<br />
<br />
<div id="test"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

My issues are:

1.) I want to display the array by writing into an HTML element, which I attempted in the for-loop. Pop-ups are to be avoided. How can I loop through HTML elements, such as demo1, demo2, demo3 etc.? I can't just write `<p id="demo" + i></p>`. What other options are there?

2.) Say I want to make use of the untilNow() function. The scope of my arrays is limited to fillArray(). Do I need to "return" the arrays to the untilNow() function as parameters?

Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current code is that you're replacing the html by the last value in every loop. You're using `=` rather than `+=`. So, a quick fix would be to replace:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
```

by:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += x;
```

An example of how you could wrap an array of strings in HTMLElements and add them to your document (note that there are many other ways/libraries to achieve the same result):

```js
var myStrings = ["Hello", "stack", "overflow"];

// Two performance rules:
// 1. Use a fragment to prevent multiple updates to the DOM
// 2. No DOM queries in the loop
var newContent = myStrings.reduce(function(result, str) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var txt = document.createTextNode(str);
  li.appendChild(txt);
  result.appendChild(li);
  
  return result;
}, document.createDocumentFragment()); 


// Actually add the new content
document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(newContent);
```

```html
<ul class="js-list"></ul>
```